# Numerical or exact solutions of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following system of differential equations:

$$x' + 3ax\sqrt{x+y} = -b\sqrt{xy}$$

$$y' + 3cy\sqrt{x+y} = b\sqrt{xy}$$

where $a, b, c$ are constant.

I appreciate  any help.

Comment: What is the independent variable?